# How can I know if a table is already arranged in ascending order in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Example, I have a table and I want to know if it is pre-arranged alphabetically descending or ascending, is there a built-in function that can do this?

Letters | Numbers |

```
A    |  1     |
B    |  2     |
```

Letters | Numbers |

```
B   |   2     |
A   |   1     |
```

thanks.

Comment: Your question shows that you don't quite understand the nature of SQL data storage. When you store data in your database, it is not stored in any particular order. When you show the data (with a `SELECT`), you can specify the order in which you want the rows to be returned (example: `select * from aTable order by letters`)

Comment: Barranka, i know all that Order BY, what i am asking is that for example, i have a table(a plane sql table). how can i know if that table is initially arranged in alphabetical order(is there a built-in function for it?) thats what i am asking, i am not asking on how to order it alphabetically because it an easy question anyone can answer it.

Comment: If you want to check whether a row set is ordered, you have to traverse it... and that would be quite an overkill, since you can ask the row set to be sorted **before** you need to traverse it. Of course you can write a stored procedure to do that, but, again, that would be overkill

Comment: well, i can check it using a loop using c, but as you said, it would be an overkill. that would be a error-prone checking but yeah, if there's not built in function for that, i guess i must do it the hard way.

Comment: Why would you want to check if a row set is sorted, if you can ask it to be sorted just by adding an `order by` clause?

Comment: well, im making a online trading card game for my project and there are buttons there that can arrange card names in an ascending fashion when clicked if it is not initially ascending. but if its initially arranged in ascending order, then it must be arranged to descending order. and vice versa.

Comment: So? You start with 'order by someField' as the order clause. When you click, you switch to 'order by someField asc'. When you click again, you switch back again. So you will *always* acquire the data in some order.

Answer (score 4):

Data in a table is **not arranged in any order**.

You have to explicitly specify an order when selecting the data. If you do not specify an order when selecting the data then the returned order is neither predictable nor reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are correct that SQL at a logical level does not guarantee that the rows are stored in any order.

But at a physical level, of course the data is stored in *some* order.  Most indexes in MyISAM and InnoDB are B-tree data structures, which by definition store values in ascending order.  In InnoDB, the table itself is stored as a clustered index in primary key order.

So the following two queries against an InnoDB table return results in the same order:

```
SELECT * FROM innodb_table;
SELECT * FROM innodb_table ORDER BY primary_key;
```

But that's a coincidence of storage implementation, not based on anything in the SQL language.

The issue is more complex if you do index-only queries against a non-primary key.  The following query will return rows in ascending order by the index used as a covering index:

```
SELECT indexed_column FROM innodb_table;
```

But as soon as you break the covering index, it reverts back to some other choice for default order (probably clustered index order again):

```
SELECT indexed_column, non_indexed_column FROM innodb_table;
```

MyISAM is totally different, because it doesn't use a clustered index.  So the default order is storage order -- which is *not* necessarily insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

Tables dont store data in a particular order. Ordering is done in order to view the data, so thats where you use `order by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You should never rely on how data is retrieved until you use ORDER BY Clause explicitly

Answer (score 1):

To add my voice to the concert of answers...

In relational databases (such as MySQL) tables must be seen as *unordered* set of rows.

As a matter on fact, you shouldn’t even rely on the fact that two identical `SELECT` statements will return the rows in the same order.

If you want to retrieve or sort your rows according to a particular order, you will have to *explicitly* request it (i.e.: using the adequate `ORDER BY` clause) *and* provide a column that allow to *deterministically* order the rows.